# Curved lines are not displayed with react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I'm using react-chart-js 2 to display continuous data in scatter chart form. I wanted to put options on the charts but some of them do not work properly or at all. So I have problems with these following option: the lines are not curved between the points and there are straight.

The version of react-chart-js 2 installed is : 5.2.0 and the version of chartJS is: 4.1.2.

**What i have tried** :

I have tried to modify the parameter in options for curve ( elements: {line: {tension: 0.1,spanGaps: false}}) but it didn't work.

Here is the code :

**App.js** :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useSyncExternalStore } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal/Modal'
import {Chart as ChartJS,LinearScale,PointElement,LineElement,Tooltip,Legend,Title,scales} from 'chart.js';
import {Scatter } from 'react-chartjs-2';
ChartJS.register(
    LinearScale,
    PointElement,
    LineElement,
    Tooltip,
    Legend,
    Title);

//JSON.parse(event.data)
//<Doughnut ref={chartReference} data={data} />
export const options1 = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio:false,
    plugins: {
      legend: false,
      title: {
        display:true,
        text: 'TWIST',
      },
    },
  };


export default function App() {
  let da;
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const [chartData1,setChartData1]=useState({
    datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Twist',
          showLine:true,
          maintainAspectRatio:false,
          fill:false,
          data: [{x:3,y:1},{x:3.5,y:2},{x:5.5,y:3},{x:5.25,y:4},{x:5,y:5}],
          backgroundColor: '#df9305',
          borderColor: '#df9305'
        }]
    });

    const [show,setShow] = useState(false);

  const chart1=(d) =>{
    setChartData1({
        datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Twist',
              showLine:true,
              fill:false,
              data: d,
              backgroundColor: '#df9305',
              borderColor: '#df9305'
            }]
    });
  };

  console.log(data)
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000');

    socket.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      setData(JSON.parse(event.data));
      da=[{x:JSON.parse(event.data)["fs"]["s1"]["twist"],y:1},
      {x:JSON.parse(event.data)["fs"]["s2"]["twist"],y:2},
      {x:JSON.parse(event.data)["fs"]["s3"]["twist"],y:3},
      {x:JSON.parse(event.data)["fs"]["s4"]["twist"],y:4},
      {x:JSON.parse(event.data)["fs"]["s5"]["twist"],y:5}];
      chart1(da);
    });

  }, []);
  
  
  return (
        <div>
            <div className="home">
                <div className="template-1" id="temp1">
                <div class="panel-3">
                    <div class="panel-header">
                    <h1>Courbes</h1>
                    <i class='bx bx-cog modal-trigger-panel'></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" >
                    <div class="graph-container" style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "row",height: "100%",width:"100%"}}>
                        <div style={{width: "25%",height: "100%"}}>
                            <Scatter options={options1} data={chartData1} />
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <Modal onClose={() => setShow(false)} show={show} />
            </div>
  );
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay this one took a while but I figured it out. I have solved it without tree shaking so that is what I will be showing, you can of course add tree shaking but I think that perhaps that is part of what is giving you trouble. To load it lazily just do

```
import 'chart.js/auto';
import { Scatter } from 'react-chartjs-2';
```

And then as I'm sure you've tried add this to options

```
elements: {
    line: {
        tension: 0.5,
    },
},
```

This way simply registers all possible registerables which will increase bundle size, this can be seen in `chart.js/auto`

```
import {Chart, registerables} from '../dist/chart.js';

Chart.register(...registerables);

export * from '../dist/chart.js';
export default Chart;
```

Where we can see that it imports all registerable items and then registers them.

### Tree-shakable way

To decrease bundle size you can choose to register manually. The minimum registerables needed for your chart are

```
import {
    Chart as ChartJS,
    LineElement,
    PointElement,
    Filler,
    LinearScale,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Scatter } from 'react-chartjs-2';
ChartJS.register(LineElement, PointElement, Filler, LinearScale);
```

If you want the tree-shakable way but have a hard time figuring out which registerables you need a surefire, though tedious way, is to just add all registerables, delete one and check that everything still works as intended and then just do this for all registerables. If you want to do this you can always use `chart.js/auto` and then correct it when you are done with the functionality, this way you wont have to worry about it every time you add new functionality. That was all the rambling I could muster hope it helps :-)

Comment: Thanks so much ! it worked but why do we need to import chart.js/auto to make it work ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure, but I have an idea of why it might be, and I'll take a look a the package and try to figure out if my suspicion is correct

Comment: Okay I've confirmed my theory. You don't need chart.js/auto this is just the lazy way to use chart.js. What happens in that file is that all controllers, elements, plugins and scales gets registered, this way you don't have to worry about not having registered enough. This is not quite as optimal as registering manually, because it will increase the bundle size, which is why it is described as the lazy method. I will update my post to include this in case anyone needs the info later on. You can read more about it here: https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/docs/migration-to-v4

Comment: Thanks i better understand how react-chartjs-2 works, I have another problem related to React that I can't solve, maybe you would understand the error I have in my code :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75170936/error-with-websocket-connection-when-trying-to-add-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for this answer - it helped me a lot. It seems to be quite difficult to know what needs to be registered because the related options just don't work rather than giving a warning or some other indication of where to look. As you note the 'easiest' way to work out what needs to be registered is to add everything and then remove them one by one and see what breaks. That seems to be a major flaw in chart.js.